# Installed Ninject and Ninject Web Api 2 extension - doesn't contain NinjectWebCommon.cs

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to use Ninject for dependency injection in my Web Api app, but there is no NinjectWebCommon.cs file in my App_Start folder.

I've tried uninstalling both Ninject and the web api extension, without any luck.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also install the Ninject.Web.Common package?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.Common/

Comment: Yes. I installed Ninject.Web.WebApi first and thereafter Ninject.Web.Common. Tried again just now with a clean project, but I don't get no NinjectWebCommon.cs file :S